# How do you enable Code suggestion feature in C# in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017

I saw something in the video, I think it was a very good feature, so that you started typing the code you were making, the program offered you to continue the code.
**I do not mean the intellisense function**, for example, you write str in the list of strings in the list

For example, by writing your own Try code, a preview of the code that should be written next (for example, you should use Catch later), like this picture.
I wanted to see how this feature is enabled in Visual Studio 2017? Because it does not work for me

[image: Visual Studio Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Can you add more clear picture from the video? It could be some third party plugin like Resharper etc.

Comment: For the try-catch example, type try and hit tab twice. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Are you referring to [code snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets)?

Comment: By pressing the Tab button twice, the whole Try and Catch code is written to us
But I do not mean writing code; the program only suggests a shadow of the code, as in the characteristic picture

Comment: That code is "shadowed" because Visual Studio has detected that the code doesn't actually do anything, and is therefore useless. Put a statement in there, and you will see the color of the code change.

Comment: No! that code not written yet!!! just showen by visual studio to help us that what we must write!

Answer (score 2):

It's called Visual Studio IntelliCode, see https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/services/intellicode/. It puts what you're most likely to use at the top of your completion list.

You enable it by installing the extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioExptTeam.VSIntelliCode.

And it's free!

Answer (score 1):

You might be thinking of [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)

Aside from suggesting code blocks and code completion it also checks your code for anything that's not true to the code style.